# Find all files in directory that have over 130 English characters or 43 asian characters

Tags: linux, shell, files

I'm trying to transfer files on my NAS, but I will get this error "The name of a file or a folder within an encrypted shared folder cannot exceed 143 English characters or 47 Asian (CJK) characters" is there a command in the shell to find every file that meets that?

Comment: Is it 130 (as per subject) or 143 (as per body)?

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, another copy is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1674690/432690).

Answer (score 1):

```
find path | grep -P '\/[^\/]{130,}[^\/]$'
```

Based on this source on stackoverflow.com:
[Find files that are too long for Synology encrypted shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938654/find-files-that-are-too-long-for-synology-encrypted-shares)

I added the $ at the end to just capture files and not folders.

Maybe you can find the CJK characters with a range of unicode. I don't think grep can do this, maybe [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep).

Comment: That assumes file paths don't contain newline characters. That also assumes you're in the C locale. Otherwise `grep`'s `[^/]` would match on characters as defined in the user's locale, not necessarily bytes. Also note that `/` should not be escaped (with `-P`, those backslash are thankfully harmless, but they wouldn't without).

Answer (score 1):

I think they're trying to say that file names, when UTF-8 encoded, cannot contain more than 143 **bytes** on the assumption that many Asian characters (whatever they meant) are encoded on 3 bytes in UTF-8 (you'll notice that 48 x 3 is 144) and most English characters are encoded on one byte¹.

So to find those:

In `zsh`:

```
set +o multibyte -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/?(#c144,)(ND)
```

For those that are above the limit and

```
set +o multibyte -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/?(#c1,143)(ND)
```

For those that are under the limit.

To see more easily the ones that are of type *directory*, you can add the `M` (for `M`ark) glob qualifier (`print -rC1 -- **/?(#c144,)(NDM)`), which will append a `/` to directories.

Or with `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*'
```

For those above the limit.

That's 144 `?`s above; you can also construct the pattern with:

```
pattern=$(printf %145s '*' | tr ' ' '?')
LC_ALL=C find . ! -name "$pattern"
```

Or in `zsh`:

```
pattern=${(l[145][?]):-*}
```

Replace `-name` with `! -name` to get those filenames that are under the limit (are made of 143 bytes or less).

With the GNU implementation of `find`, you can also do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[^/]{144,}'
```

---

<sup>¹ The UTF-8 encoding encodes characters on 1 to 4 bytes (initially the algorithm was designed to encode code points up to U+7FFFFFF on up to 6 bytes, but Unicode code points have been later restricted to U+10FFFF), only the characters from the US-ASCII set (codepoints U+0000 to U+007F) are encoded on one byte. The ones encoded on 3 bytes are the ones from U+0800 to U+FFFF.</sup>